# How to import React experimental hooks correctly?

Tags: reactjs, npm

I'm trying to learn and some of the unreleased "unstable" features of React. In particular, I want to use the "useEffectEvent" hook.

The problem is that I can't import that part of the package in any way.

When I try to import something from the React official package in this way:

```
import * as React from "react"
```

The module automatically points to this directory (the @types/react npm package)

```
node_modules/@types/react/index"
```

The experimental hooks (such as "React.experimental_useEffectEvent") are here though:

```
node_modules/react/index"
```

This happens both with CRA and Vite, and I tried with standard JS builds (no TS, no tsconfig file).

How can I reach that part of React's code?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two (or three) aspects of this (both shown in [the documentation](https://react.dev/reference/react/experimental_useEffectEvent), though #2 is a bit subtle [it's at the top, but not in the code sample]):

1. You have to be using the `react@experimental` and `react-dom@experimental` modules.
2. The hook's name is `experimental_useEffectEvent`, not just `useEffectEvent`.

So:

```
import { experimental_useEffectEvent } from "react";
// ...
experimental_useEffectEvent(/*...*/);
```

or perhaps (for now):

```
import { experimental_useEffectEvent as useEffectEvent } from "react";
// ...
useEffectEvent(/*...*/);
```

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-phoebe-zr5y7w?file=/src/App.js)

If you're using TypeScript, you'll want to read the instructions in the `@types/react` module's `experimental.d.ts` file to see how to get TypeScript to recognize the experimental hooks. There are a couple of different ways; one of the simpler ones is to add this to any file in the project (I used `App.tsx`):

```
/// <reference types="react/experimental" />
```

FWIW, here's how I bootstrapped a new project using the experimental features:

1. `npm create vite@latest` (I use Vite.js as my bundler).

   - Chose React from the list
   - Chose TypeScript from the list
2. `npm install react@experimental react-dom@experimental`
3. Replaced the pre-supplied `App.tsx` with:

   ```
   /// <reference types="react/experimental" />
   import { experimental_useEffectEvent as useEffectEvent } from "react";
   import "./App.css";

   function App() {
       return <div>typeof useEffectEvent: {typeof useEffectEvent}</div>;
   }

   export default App;
   ```

When I run that, I get `typeof useEffectEvent: function` on the page.

I don't use `create-react-app`, but I did briefly try it, but ran into dependency issues upgrading React to the experimental version.

Comment: Idk, but still doesn't work. Ran:
- npx create-react-app my-app
- npm install react@experimental react-dom@experimental
- npm install -D eslint-plugin-react-hooks@experimental

The correct experimental versions appears in the package.json file. But still not able to import "experimental_useEffectEvent".

Managed to solve it with Vite and Typescript build though. Just added "types": ['react/experimental"] to the tsconfig file. Weird.

Comment: I replicated it in Codesandbox but locally I'm still not able. I install the experimental packages but still can't find any "experimental_useEffectEvent" in the module.

Comment: @fra.mstr - I don't use create-react-app. I tried just now and got dependency issues but again, I don't use it so may not have known of a hoop to jump through. I didn't have any trouble bootstrapping a new project with Vite.js (my usual bundler), though. I've also added a note above about getting TypeScript to recognize the new hooks (it's covered in the `experimental.d.ts` file in `@types/react`). HTH!